# Queue to store costs about transactions

Tags: java, queue

I intend on storing 6 of these values within a queue and when it reaches the limit 6 it will implement the FIFO measurements.

My question is how will I be able to show details that are of a string data type such as what the name of the transaction was, the corporation involved etc etc. I clearly can't do that within the queue; only holds one data type.

```
//Both are declared in a class
private float Amount; 
Queue <Float> Transactions = new LinkedList <Float>();

//In a method via a parameter to add to a queue
Transactions.offer(Cost);
```

New Example:

```
public void New_Transaction(String Transaction, float Cost, String 
Date_Time) {                            
    Transaction_Type = Transaction;
    Transactions.offer(Cost);
    Date_an_Time = Date_Time;        
}
```

Comment: what is the meaning of your edit? This is clearly not a class as suggestion, nor is it the constructor of a class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    static class Transaction{
    String name;
    double amount;
    String from;
    String to;
    long timeOfTheTransaction;

    public Transaction() {
    }

    public Transaction(String name, double amount, String from, String to, long timeOfTheTransaction) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.timeOfTheTransaction = timeOfTheTransaction;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public long getTimeOfTheTransaction() {
        return timeOfTheTransaction;
    }

    public void setTimeOfTheTransaction(long timeOfTheTransaction) {
        this.timeOfTheTransaction = timeOfTheTransaction;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<Transaction> transactions=new LinkedList<Transaction>();
    if(transactions.size()<=6){
        ((LinkedList<Transaction>) transactions).addFirst(new Transaction());
    }else{
        ((LinkedList<Transaction>) transactions).removeLast();
        ((LinkedList<Transaction>) transactions).addFirst(new Transaction());
    }
}
}
```

I have created a transaction class, you can edit based on your need. I am checking the size for each insertion. If i see size is greater than 6, I remove the last element and add the new one. Thanks

Comment: Woah, many thanks Omar for this example, I will go away and analyse this example, then implement this in my own example.

Comment: If you think, that is what you need, can you accept that answer please?

Comment: Only downside is I wont know if my code works until it has been implemented into a Graphical User Interface

Comment: Ok. It is up to you as long as you accept correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You create an object with the name of the transaction, the corporation involved, and others as the fields then use the object as the data type of your Queue  Transactions. Hope this helps.

Comment: I get what you meaning, something along the lines of this in a method for my class to represent transactions for instance: the example is the edit above